# Can people upload to my OneDrive?

Tags: onedrive

I created a folder and shared the edit link, but when the person tried uploading a file they got the message:

> Sorry, you don't have permission to add files to this folder.

Is the Edit link only so people can modify files that already exist?

Is there a way to let them upload new ones?